# Linux encrypted password

Tags: linux, password

I'm useing linux command useradd and I have problem. I crypted password and add user but not put all pass like:

Password: 7856

Encrypted password: $1$ky6XlX5g$mu6Wva/vTJgZF9.p8tyAq/

Example:
`useradd -m -p '$1$ky6XlX5g$mu6Wva/vTJgZF9.p8tyAq/' username`

I look to shadow file and not all password saved, just a slice of encrypted password.

Saved peace: /vTJgZF9.p8tyAq/

I need exactly command: `useradd -m -p`

Comment: You mention you are using PHP.  Are you sure that your system isn't trying to evaluate `$ky6XlX5g` as if it was a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may solve your particular problem...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to add a user to Linux system
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
    read -p "Enter username : " username
    read -s -p "Enter password : " password
    egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$username exists!"
        exit 1
    else
        pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
        useradd -m -p $pass $username
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
    fi
else
    echo "Only root may add a user to the system"
    exit 2
fi
```

Comment: I need to know my error reason, it good script but I need like my example. Meabe it impossible?

Comment: There are many reasons your method is failing, namely the way crypt() works.

Comment: your method is failing most likely due to useradd decrypting the encrypted password and re-encrypting it silently. this is expected behavior with useradd, so to accomplish your goal, you will need a script like the one I posted. It's a simple bash script which you can put in a plain text file and call it from any other application or script if you mark it executable and place it somewhere in your $PATH

Comment: how modify this scritp that I can execute like ./add.sh username password? sorry I just scripting in php...

Comment: create a new empty file, copy the script EXACTLY as it appears and save the file. This script will then be run ./scriptname it will then prompt you for a username and password. In php you can include some expect logic, or change the bash script to accept command line parameters.

Comment: @tagram, passwords are hashed, not encrypted.  You cannot decrypt them.

Comment: The same problem since this post. I useing this script, some passwords are saved in half... What a problem I do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

You mention you are using PHP and SSH.  Are you sure that your system isn't trying to evaluate `$ky6XlX5g` as if it was a variable?  Both PHP and Bash use this syntax, perhaps you haven't properly escaped the command you are sending via SSH.

I ask this because I just ran your command on my local system and it seems to work exactly like it should.  I suspect something else is happening, and the command is not actually being passed correctly.

```
root@hostname:# useradd -m -p '$1$ky6XlX5g$mu6Wva/vTJgZF9.p8tyAq/' username
root@hostname:# grep username /etc/shadow
username:$1$ky6XlX5g$mu6Wva/vTJgZF9.p8tyAq/:15206:0:99999:7:::
root@hostname:~
```

Comment: And I tryed with putty program but it same error like ssh2... tagram script is good solution in my way. Maybe you don't get because your local system...

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to decrypt it before adding. Maybe u can use a python script to do that. You can substitute the compression technique below with your encryption technique :

```
import zlib
import os

def useradd(pass_string,username):
    password=zlib.decompress(pass_string)
    os.system('useradd -m -p'+password+' '+username)

useradd('x\x9c3\xb705\x03\x00\x02(\x00\xdb',username)
```

You can arrive at that parse string by just typing python on you command line, and in the interpreter you can type

```
import zlib
zlib.compress('7856')
```

This will output

```
'x\x9c3\xb705\x03\x00\x02(\x00\xdb'
```

Hope it is clear. You can just substitute the zlib compression with your encryption technique.

Comment: I need to know why not all pass saved and how do it, because I'm using ssh2 with php.

Comment: Yeah u can also do it that way !!