# Strange record in /etc/shadow after useradd -p and crypt function in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, shadow

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
There is [a simple **bash script**](https://serverfault.com/questions/303338/linux-encrypted-password) to **add a new user** via command line in interactive mode:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to add a user to Linux system
if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
    read -p "Enter username : " username
    read -s -p "Enter password : " password
    egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$username exists!"
        exit 1
    else
        pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
        useradd -m -p $pass $username
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
    fi
else
    echo "Only root may add a user to the system"
    exit 2
fi
```

The result inside the `/etc/shadow` file after adding the user through that script looks pretty weird.
For example for *username* `demo` and *password* `demo`, the `useradd` command adding to `/etc/shadow` file:

```
demo:paR7EXftedvjA:19081:0:99999:7:::
```

There is no information about `id`, `param`, and `salt` as it should be described in the currently accepted form.
Looks like it's just a hash or I don't know what is that `paR7EXftedvjA`. I've tried to get it back using `demo` as salt and `demo` as password in commands like `mkpasswd` or `openssl` but the result is not the same.

Comment: I don't know how to resolve the problem. However, there are quite a few problems with this code. Paste it into https://www.shellcheck.net for some assistance. It's possible the plaintext or encrypted password got mangled due to the missing quotes.

Comment: I have added missed quotes but it is not the reason of my problem.

Comment: Your perl (or more likely the platform or OS it is running on, which you didn't mention) is using the 'traditional' tweaked-DES method [described here](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/crypt) which was many years before the invention of [the 'modular' syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)). `openssl passwd -crypt -salt pa demo` produces exactly `paR7EXftedvjA`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you! Your comment has dispelled my doubts.